# How to set target property of Json Object

Tags: java, json

I have a question about Json objects. Currently I am developing a Spring MVC application. One of functionality in this app is to set href property to json Object.
Example:

```
JsonObject tempJsonObject = new JsonObject();
tempJsonObject.addProperty("href", "result?buildDir=" + randompath);
```

My question is: How I can set "target" property of this object? I want by clicking on this link result opens in iframe.
I have tried

```
tempJsonObject.addProperty("target", "iframeName");
```

but this didn't work.

Thank you in advance!

Solution: As [Sotirios Delimanolis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438154/sotirios-delimanolis) advаice me I use jQuery for this problem: 
 $('a').attr('target', 'iframeResult');  this select all 'a' elements and put attribute 'target' which target to iframe with name = iframeResult

Comment: You'll need to do that with javascript. Get the `href` element and set the iframe location to the url.

Comment: Thank you very much. I achieved my goal with jQuery:
$('a').attr('target', 'iframeResult');

Comment: @user2739823 Add it as answer in order to be helpfull for others. :)

Comment: and what happens to that JSON object? Because it's not an HTML link element, so what's the code that turns it into a link? Setting targets on all `<a>` elements is not a true solution, it's a workaround.

Comment: Yes, you are right that this JSON Object is not an HTML link element, but for my application I need to set href and target property to JSON Object, and after that to create a grid with ExtJS. This Object will be my store for the grid and for this purpose it works for me fine to get all <a> tags and set to them target attribute with jQuery. Probably in other situation it will not be useful approach but for me works great! :)